# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multipartform-data, api-gateway

I am trying to pass the file to microservice from api_gateway, I can get the file in api_gateway from reactjs but in my microservice I am getting **PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large error in nodejs**

**API gateway**

```
 const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
      form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (files.file) {
          const url = api.host + req.originalUrl;
          let formData = new FormData();
          console.log(files)

          formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(files.file.filepath));
          axios.post(url, formData, {})
          .then((response) => {
            return res.status(response.status).send(response.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (!err.response)
              return res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
            return res.status(err.response.status).send(err);
          });
```

**Multer code in microservice**

```
const DIR = 'public/uploads';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
        cb(null, fileName)
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype == "video/mp4") {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
            return cb(new Error('Only .mp4 format allowed!'));
        }
    }
});
```

**router.js**

```
router.post("/profile", (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.file);
   const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
   form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
     console.log("Fields", fields);
     console.log("Files", files);
     console.log(err);
  });
});
```

**API gateway index.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '500mb', extended: true}));
```

**Microservice index.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

Comment: are you using body-parser in the API gateway? Increase the body size.

Comment: I have increased the limit till 500mb still getting the same error